# How to get a "rechargable" chemical reaction for a glow stick

Tags: photochemistry

I want to create my own glow stick that lasts a while while ligting up the surroundings. How would I go about this? I know there are youtube videos and such. But the way they do it doesn't allow for any way of "recharging"

How can i make a "rechargable" glow stick?

Comment: What qualifies as recharging?  Adding more of a compound?  Heating/cooling?  Waiting a while?  Toxicity requirements?  If you're looking for a cheap, nontoxic glowstick that will relight after you leave it in the freezer for an hour, that would be a seriously valuable commodity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Chemoluminescent** processes based on the reaction of diaryloxalates with hydrogen peroxide in the presence of a fluorescent dye are **not reversible**.

While the dye remains unchanged, both the oxalates and the hydrogen peroxide are consumed. "Recharging" a device (glow stick) isn't possible. When performing the reaction in a flask, only could probably prolong the light emission by subsequently adding portions of the starting materials over time.

**Photoluminescent** *glow-in-the-dark* devices based on the emission of long-lived excited triplet states can indeed be "recharged" by holding the device in the light again. But this has nothing to do with the reactions happening in glow sticks.