# 3 chemicals to produce light

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I'm actually looking for 2 chemicals that will produce a really small exothermic reaction. The 3rd chemical would be there to separate the chemicals - like oil,  water, and air.

Ideally, the 3rd chemical would be a nonreactive oxide of the other 2.

Also, they should all stay liquid on a hot summer's day.

As stated, they should produce a small exothermic reaction - I'm looking for mostly light that won't melt a glass bottle.
Melting the bottle isn't ideal, but I can find a stronger material too.

Also, the chemicals should be as nontoxic as possible. They don't have to be though.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. A chemical flashlight? A bomb? This experiment is the closest one to your description: youtube.com/watch?v=Nyzlt-dVgWQ

Comment: I'm making a bottle of liquid that lights up. Explosion = failure. It would be used as a random shake-timer. Shake it and it lights up for a while, and then it would separate back out into it's original form.

Comment: You can buy these as light sticks. Why, because  the chemicals are expensive, difficult to obtain and not pleasant to use.

Comment: Well I can give you a recipe for a solution that is colorless, turns blue when shaken, then it again becomes colorless after a while. The process can be repeated many times, and it doesn't require very sophisticated reagents. If you need light, then I guess you would have to look for some chemiluminescent reactions, but most of such reactions require some organic reagents that are not easy to get.

Comment: I would definitely use a light stick, however, usually they are one use, and last way too long. I'm sort of looking for a way to halt the reaction after an amount of time, and then reinitiating it by remixing the medium.

Comment: Is there a way to use the blue to refract an ultraviolet or infrared light source to something visible? If so, I would be REALLY interested. How safe is it?

Comment: With the thing I had in mind it is not possible, but it would be doable with some other chemical systems; I will try to find some later, but they might include some exotic chemicals. In my original idea, the blue color can be made intense enough to block visible light, e.g., from a flashlight. It would be an inverse of what you wanted: light goes out when shaken then it slowly returns to nominal intensity, but I don't know if that suits you.

Comment: I wonder if I could start and stop the process with another chemical? Like an on/off switch? What is the recipe in question? I'm close to giving up on the whole 'chemical producing light when agitated' thing.

Comment: You can make two solutions that produce light when mixed. Then you take an excess of one solution, add a small portion of the second solution - it will produce a glow until the reagent in the second solution is exhausted, then you can add another portion and so on.

Comment: Post that as an answer. I had an idea. Also include the most nontoxic 2 solutions you can think of on the spot - and a unreactive, buoyant 3rd.

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24945/how-to-get-a-rechargable-chemical-reaction-for-a-glow-stick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments... The two component chemiluminescence reaction:
(Solution 1) To 50 ml of deionized water add 10-50 mg of luminol, 10-20 ml of 10% ammonia solution and 1-5 ml of 3% hydrogen peroxide. (Solution 2) To 100 ml of deionized water add few milligrams of copper salt (e.g., sulfate) or few drops of blood or fresh horseradish juice. These are approximate quantities (they should work), but you can experiment with the concentrations, after all experimenting is the most fun part of chemistry. Now take the solution 2 (whole) and add few milliliters of solution 1 to it and shake it. You should be able to observe a faint glow. A brighter emission requires organic solvents (DMSO, DMF) and corrosive chemicals (KOH). Adding a third liquid that will separate the two other (as the OP suggested) is not a simple thing to do. I would do this otherwise: add some neutral ingredient to solution 2 to increase its density (possibly sugar, but I'm not sure if that will not quench the chemiluminescence) and place the solution in a container (preferably a long tube). Then carefully pour the solution 1 on the surface of the solution 2 (so that the solutions won't mix). When you shake the container the solutions will mix and produce glow. Another idea: place one solution in a container and layer it with a hot paraffin from a candle and allow it to cool down. Then you can pour the second solution on the solid paraffin. To start the reaction, simply break the thin paraffin layer by shaking (you can place some glass marbles in the container).

Comment: You totally got the vibe of my question :-) I am trying to make a working staff that will have a bottle at the top that glows like alchemy or magic would. Now I can play pokemon go and scare away crazy thieves with something nonsensical and my staff! Mwahahahaha!

Comment: Also, would something like a Klein bottle work to measure a little of the 1st solution? Or is that too imprecise?